# GAE suddenly can't access my apps!

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, dashboard

I'm using Google App Engine for a number of sites I host.

As of a short time ago GAE won't allow me to login via the usual.

https://appengine.google.com/a/websitename.com

It keeps telling me that I'm "Unauthorized." I.e I can't access the dashboard for any of my apps!

This was working fine as of a few days ago and I've not made any changes.

Is there any way that I can sort this out? I.e. can I remotely add a role to my app for example. Is there another way of logging into the dashboard etc?

Any help would be fantastic as this is really causing me serious problems.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Sounds like it's best to contact Google support.

Comment: Can you access the part of the dashboard that lists all your apps (eg, at the URL you provided)? Have you changed anything, such as upgrading your domain's accounts, lately? Have you tried clearing your cookies and logging in again?

Comment: Did you ever sort it out? Started seeing this myself lately. @NickJohnson listing the apps fails too; some time later the problem mysteriously disappears.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to reach the app dashboard, the proper url format for the moment is `https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=some_app_id`.  That being said, you shouldn't depend too much on that as it's an implementation detail that's subject to change whenever.

Next time, try visiting `http://appengine.google.com/` for the list of apps your account has access to.

Comment: He's already going to the right URL for a Google Apps account.

Comment: I thought that URL scheme was deprecated after Google switched to the new way of handling multi-user accounts?  I have a google apps account myself, and am logged into both regular gmail and that account, `appengine.google.com` asks which account I want to use whenever I log in.

Comment: It's no longer necessary, but it won't do any harm to go to it.